# Pass variable into jQuery CSS value to calculate height

Tags: jquery, css, height, calc

I desprately need to set this DIV "two" height to be calculated as 100% - *(minus)* another DIV height (div "one"). The thing is, the height of that another DIV (div "one") is dynamic already.

So:

```
<body>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
</body>

div { position: relative; }
body { height: 100vh; }
```

I tried things like these, but that doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(exe);
$(window).resize(exe);

function exe(){
    var topHeight = $('#one').outerHeight(true);
    $('#two').css("height", "calc(100% - topHeight)")
}
```

or

```
$(document).ready(exe);
$(window).resize(exe);

function exe(){
    var topHeight = $('#one').outerHeight(true);
    var topHeightCalc = '100%' - topHeight;
    $('#two').css("height", topHeightCalc)
}
```

Comment: String concatenation `$('#two').css("height", "calc(100% - " + topHeight + ")")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey friend you can also achieve what you want without using the calc() function.

This gets height of the window and deduct height of the div `#one` from that and apply that height to div `#two`.

```
$(document).ready(exe);
$(window).resize(exe);

function exe(){
    var topHeight = $('#one').outerHeight(true);
    var vhHeight = $(window).outerHeight(true);
    $('#two').css("height", vhHeight - topHeight + "px");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct string concatenation in the CSS value to `"calc(100% - "+ topHeight +"px)"`

```js
$(document).ready(exe);
$(window).resize(exe);

function exe(){
    var topHeight = $('#one').outerHeight(true);
    $('#two').css("height", "calc(100% - "+ topHeight +"px)")
}
```

```css
div { position: relative; }
body { height: 100vh; margin:0}

#one {background:#eee}
#two {background:#666}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec auctor lobortis aliquet. Fusce sed neque quis eros pulvinar pulvinar quis tincidunt sem. In maximus elementum sagittis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce at sollicitudin dolor. Quisque diam ipsum, porta vel eros sed, pellentesque pellentesque odio. Nunc neque lorem, tincidunt eget quam in, interdum dignissim arcu. Cras dapibus felis in facilisis interdum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</div>
<div id="two">asdf</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more *extravagant* way of doing this, if [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) is not an issue, is to use **display: table**. This way you can achieve your desired effect without using any JS.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container__table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container__tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.container__td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.container__td#one {
  height: 1%;
}

/* Unnecessary style */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

.container__td {
  padding: 15px;
}

#one {
  background-color: #bababa;
}

#two {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container__table">
    <div class="container__tr">
      <div id="one" class="container__td">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto molestias excepturi accusantium quidem porro, ut doloremque qui minus dolores, vel voluptate aliquid ipsum laborum ea libero, asperiores sed. Hic nihil itaque maxime error dolorum similique quod, et, deleniti quo quas cupiditate necessitatibus eius dignissimos! Harum praesentium accusamus officia impedit quaerat voluptate minima aut dolore, quibusdam voluptas! Voluptatem similique dignissimos officiis, eligendi repellendus aspernatur, consectetur quam nemo assumenda, nihil doloribus dicta ducimus modi, atque dolorum sequi voluptate ipsam quos blanditiis. Deserunt praesentium dolorem id eius error tempora. Rem ipsam blanditiis, aliquid eos fuga facilis, perspiciatis soluta, distinctio ea sequi, explicabo dolore.<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur molestias sint saepe debitis ab aliquid eum harum eligendi, similique perferendis fuga, illum tempore, pariatur nobis tempora reprehenderit eius laboriosam. Doloribus nihil vitae at atque eaque!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container__tr">
      <div id="two" class="container__td">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ducimus, repudiandae excepturi velit maxime dolore. Esse quis similique fugit eligendi quae sequi numquam et unde adipisci possimus ea eius maxime eveniet, itaque voluptate recusandae magnam ducimus dolorem explicabo mollitia nisi porro asperiores ratione. Libero, sint, sapiente. Pariatur et, repellat iure!<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni harum ullam amet nihil iusto maiores cupiditate cumque alias hic unde!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```